# How to implement checkbox in listview xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement checkbox in listview and retrieve the data from the selected rows. I tried searching online, but i am not finding any proper resource and some plugins are already not working anymore. Any reference and approach from anyone will be very kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MVVM to achieve it. Here is running GIF.

[image]

First of all, you can create a Model. Add your need binding properties.

```
  public class MyModel:BaseViewModel
    {
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Then create a Viewmodel to pop data.

```
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MyModel> myModels { get; set; }
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            myModels =new  ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { IsChecked = false, Title = "test1" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { IsChecked = false, Title = "test2" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { IsChecked = false, Title = "test3" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { IsChecked = false, Title = "test4" });
            myModels.Add(new MyModel() { IsChecked = false, Title = "test5" });
        }
    }
```

Then Create a layout to display the data.

```
       <ListView  x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding myModels}"  ItemSelected="listView_ItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee"
                        Orientation="Vertical">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"></CheckBox>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="#f35e20" />

                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Here is background code for the layout, then retrieve the data from the selected rows and make a bindingContext.

```
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
        }

        private void listView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var myModel=e.SelectedItem as MyModel;
            DisplayAlert("title",myModel.Title+" "+myModel.IsChecked,"OK");
        }
    }
```